# Android GSM/CDMA cell reload

Tags: android, reload, gsm, cdma

I have problem (challenge) with my app. I want to be connected to the "best" GSM or CDMA cell - the closest, with the best signal, etc... As I turned off the cell-phone functions and turned it on back. That is the thing I want to do in my app, because I need to have the most recent informations of location without using GPS or any data.

Can I find the way, how to force Android to refind the GSM/CDMA cell?

Lot of thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

For GSM, the cell you are connected to is decided by the network. The network tells the device which cell to use and also when to perform an handover,.i.e. change the cell. I would assume that this functionality is deeply buried in the hardware/firmware of your device with no chance to change it

Comment: And do you think there is a way to force rescan? I hoped that switching to airplanmode on/off helps, but after doing that I have to unlock my SIM (:'(). Another way is switching GSM / CDMA / combined mode. This triggers rescan, but I don't know the way to do this from source code and I'm afraid thats not possible.

Comment: For GSM: switching off airplane mode will trigger that the phone attaches to the network. In essence the the phone will announce itself and immediatelly the network will instruct the phone which cell to use. So