# In android, How to change the default Cell that the phone is using

Tags: android

I use getAllCellInfo api to get all the cell Information list , choose the biggest Signal Strength level from the list. And use reflect to set its isRegistered value is true. but the network signal level does not change  in my phone.
the code:

```
   List<CellInfo> infos = tel.getAllCellInfo();
    if (infos != null) {
        for (CellInfo info1 : infos) { 
            if (info1 instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = ((CellInfoLte) info1).getCellSignalStrength();

                try {
                    Method setRegistered = ((CellInfoLte) info1).getClass().getMethod("setRegistered", Boolean.TYPE);
                    if (cellSignalStrengthLte.getLevel() == 4 && !isFirstTime) {
                        setRegistered.invoke(((CellInfoLte) info1), true);
                        isFirstTime = true;
                    } else {
                        setRegistered.invoke(((CellInfoLte) info1), false);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Is there any way to  let my phone use the cell that has biggest signal level ?

Comment: this answer suggests you can't do it, actually this is because the network tells the mobile which cell to use, not the other way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772055/android-gsm-cdma-cell-reload

Comment: There are some  network enhancer apps in app store, why can  these apps do the thing?

Comment: i am not sure how do they work, maybe they switch to airplane mode and back to online instantly, for (1 second or less) so the device will lose signal and reconnect to the best available one.

Comment: because if such thing is possible/doable it would be included on the OS as standard feature, for sure. but IMO they can't because it involves the operator network, how many devices is connected to this (stronger) cell, can we add new device, can we ... etc. so this was left in the hand of the operator to decide which cell to use. they -signal enhance and boost apps- override this with a hack, that could be as i mentioned something involves forcing the device to reconnect.